# Ajax, call multiple PHP function from a single js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a trouble with my project.
In my site i have a page html with a single button and at onclick() eventa js function call intro.js, trough a XmlHttpRequestObject  have to do many calls at many php function, in detail:

in js  i call scan() function

```
function scan() {
 if (xmlHttp)
 {
 // try to connect to the server
 try
 {
  // initiate reading the async.txt file from the server
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "php/intro.php?P1=http://"+oStxt.value, true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  // change cursor to "busy" hourglass icon
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";    
}
// display the error in case of failure
catch (e)
{
  alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
  // revert "busy" hourglass icon to normal cursor
   document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
}

}
```

And in handleRequestStatuschange i have:

```
function handleRequestStateChange()
 {
 // obtain a reference to the <div> element on the page
 // display the status of the request 
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
 {
 // revert "busy" hourglass icon to normal cursor
document.body.style.cursor = "default";
// read response only if HTTP status is "OK"
if (xmlHttp.status == 200) 
{
  try
  {
    // read the message from the server
    response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    // display the message 
document.body.appendChild(oRtag);
oPch = document.getElementById("divRtag");
oOch = document.createTextNode(response);
oPch.appendChild(oOch);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    // display error message
    alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
  }
} 
else
{
    // display status message
  alert("There was a problem retrieving the data:\n" + 
        xmlHttp.statusText);
  // revert "busy" hourglass icon to normal cursor
  document.body.style.cursor = "default"; 
}
}
}
```

It works for just one php call, but i need to call different php page in scan function after intro.php (scan2.php, scan3.php, ecc ecc) and with json_decode write single data of the array that return in div tags on my html page.
Which is the best way to call different php pages and manage the results with a single js function in ajax?

Thanks in advance
Alessandro

Comment: You'd send a single request to a `PHP` file, that would call one function, which would call *many* PHP Functions within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you built your php-functions. Cant you create a function, that calls other functions (scans)?

```
function doScan(){

  $data = array();

 //like this, or with a loop
 $data['scan1'] = scan1();
 ....
 $data['scanN'] = scanN();

echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: Yes, but there are many many php file to call and return data. I wanted to avoid creating a giant array to run then in js

Comment: @almal I think you're missing the point, it would make 1000 times more sense to call many PHP `n` number of functions in a single AJAX request rather than `n` number of AJAX Calls. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the simplest method that comes to mind is just to parameterise this function. This is as simple as

```
function doScan(url) { // Code here }
```

Then simply make the exact same ajax request with the `url` variable.

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "php/" + url + "?P1=http://"+oStxt.value, true);
```

Next, simply call the `doScan` function with various parameters.

```
doScan("index.php");
doScan("otherPage.php");
doScan("somethingElse.php");
```

This will make ajax requests on the PHP file that you specify.